# Parallel straight lines

Tags: geometry

Which are the parallel lines?
[image]

I prove that $a$ and $b$ are parallel but can't prove that $c$ and $d$ are parallel.
The angles, which are $135^o$ and $45^o$ are alternate angles.They aren't equal , so $c$ *isn't* parallel to $d$ but the answer is that $c$ is parallel to $d$. Am I right that they aren't?

**Edit**:
They are a little inclined like these:
[image: http://www.math10.com/f/download/file.php?id=1169]

Comment: To put it simply, yes. If the answer is that they are parallel, I suspect there is more to this than your description allows.

Comment: Moreover, if the angles are how you say they are, then $C$ and $D$ are perpendicular...

Comment: Could you please post or link to the full original problem for reference?

Comment: Have you tried making an *accurate* drawing?

Comment: @Carter , they aren't perpendicular.My drawing is wrong.

Comment: @J.M they are a little inclined.

Comment: Note that $135+45=180$.

Comment: @Filmus ,yes but they must be adjacent angels to do this ,mustn't they?

Comment: @lam3r4370, draw the picture accurately and you will see that $C$ and $D$ are, in fact, perpendicular to one another. This is not based on the drawing, but on the angles that you gave.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with extra information. Part of solving problems is knowing what to ignore! You are thinking about 4 lines, but to show two lines are parallel, you only really need 3.

So, you don't need to use **all** of the information given to solve this problem. In fact, you can *ignore line d* and just focus on how line c interacts with the lines you want to prove are parallel.

Next look at the theorem about parallel lines and their [transverse](http://www.mathnstuff.com/math/spoken/here/2class/260/trans.htm) again.

Then, you should have your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Use corresponding angles to see if the lines are parallel.  Note if the alternate interior angles are congruent.  This will prove if any of these two pairs might fall under the category of Euclidean parallel lines.